# FUELPHP Database Exceprtion :- General error: 20018 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: php, sql-server, fuelphp

Recently i have migrated my code form vm to docker .Its working good in the docker except for some DB operation..
During a save operation i am getting some Database error related to **MSSQL** Date and time.

My php version is **7.2.19**.And the database is **MSSQL**

I tried to add an entry "mssql.datetimeconvert = Off" in the php.ini config.but it didn't worked for me.

Also i copied the SQL Query from the error message and executed in the Database using HeidiSql Tool.Its working fine with the SQL tool.

updated_at column type is  DATETIME2 with default NULL.

invoice_date column type is  DATE with default NULL.

delinquent_date column type is  DATE with default NULL.

I am getting the following error When i submitted my form.

```
 Fuel\Core\Database_Exception [ HY000 (20018) ]:
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. [20018] (severity 16)
 [UPDATE "invoices" SET "invoice_date" = '0', "delinquent_date" = '2019-07-21', "updated_at" = '2019-06-21 00:10:16', "fd_amount" = 321.000000, "invoice_late_fee" = 0, "invoice_subtotal" = 338.000000, "invoice_total" = 338.000000 WHERE "id" = 134536] with query: 
  "UPDATE "invoices" SET "invoice_date" = '0', "delinquent_date" = '2019-07-21', "updated_at" = '2019-06-21 00:10:16', "fd_amount" = 321.000000, "invoice_late_fee" = 0, "invoice_subtotal" = 338.000000, "invoice_total" = 338.000000 WHERE "id" = 134536"
```

Comment: `"0"` isnt a date, isn't a string representation and of a number. The error seems quite clear here

Comment: @Larnu  Thanks for the quick reply. But the same  query is working in the AZURE VM  and in the heidiSql tool.that's why am confused .

Comment: Data type change? Either way, what is the date `'0'` meant to represent? I doubt the the date of the invoice really was 01 January 1900; so seems like you should be using `NULL` here.

Comment: @Larnu  Yes its exactly the same issue you have mentioned in your comment. All the dates from the MSSQL Db is not formatted as the system expected.So all dates are invalid dates-"00-00-0000"